# setting cookie on php login script

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication

After going back to one of 'PHP Login System' test projects, I now need to create a wait so that I can set a cookie so that the user is remembered when they re-visit the website, this can either be a cookie that is set with or without a remember me option, whichever is best.

Here is the php coding that authenicates a user after they've entered their login information.

```
<?php
session_start();    // Create the session
if (empty($_REQUEST['username']) || empty($_REQUEST['password'])) { header("Location: /login.php?username=" . $_REQUEST['username'] . "&message=0"); exit; 
} else { 

$username = $_POST['username']; // Gets the username
$password = $_POST['password']; // Gets the password.
$salt = "n4tOqSYcZI5Y463oG34T7YR8Q72hVU"; // random string

// Add some salt
$salt .= $password; 
$password = $salt; // new salted pass.

// Encrypt the password.
$password = md5($password);

include('settings.php');
include('dbconnect.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1"; 
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); // just to be sure.
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$resusername = $row['username']; 
$respassword = $row['password'];
$resemail = $row['email'];
}

// valid user?

if ($respassword == $password) {

// Yes they are.
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1";
$_SESSION['email'] = $resemail;
$_SESSION['username'] = $resusername;

$SQL = "UPDATE xxx SET usr_lastlogin='" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "',lastlogin_ip='" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";
$result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Process 2");

header('Location: /index.php');

} else {

// No
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "0";
header("Location: /login.php?username=" . $_REQUEST['username'] . "&message=3"); 
exit; } 
}
?>
```

Where would I need to start, with getting that code to also create the cookie information that is stored on a users computer, either with or without a remember me option, which ever is best.

Thanks for any help and assistance in advanced.

Comment: In simple, you want to create a cookie that stores "Remember Me" option, exact?

Comment: You're hashing the password, not 'encrypting' it. Also if security is important to your project then you could (and should) do a lot better than md5. Try using: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: @Frederick Marcoux - Yes, in simple I would like to create a cookie that stores the information to remember the visitor to the site.

Comment: @ajnatural - I'll have a look at that for future reference, at the moment the hashing of the password seems to be working, with the salted added to the beginning of the password before it is md5-ed, I've not been able to reverse any hashed passwords that I've tried out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and read it out of $_COOKIE later. Have a look at setcookie() and as far as using $_COOKIE goes it's pretty much the same as session:

```
function isLoggedIn(){
    if($_COOKIE['loggedin'] == true or $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```